# Mail Merge Macro: How to send data from each row in my Excel sheet to different pages on Word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have been working on a macro that adds data to a page on Word in the form of a Mail Merge label. I found a code online that gets all the data into one page on Word. I was wondering if there is a way that the data from each row in my Excel Spreadsheet could go to different pages in Word? The code is given below.

```
Sub LabelMerge()

   Dim oWord As Word.Application, oDoc As Word.Document
   Dim sPath As String, I As Integer, oHeaders As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Set oHeaders = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows(1)
   sPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
   Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
   oWord.Visible = True
   oDoc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdMailingLabels
   oWord.Dialogs(wdDialogLabelOptions).Show
   oDoc.Activate

   With oDoc.MailMerge.Fields

     For I = 1 To oHeaders.Columns.Count
       .Add oWord.Selection.Range, oHeaders.Cells(1, I)
       oWord.Selection.TypeText " "
     Next I

   End With

   oDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource sPath
   oWord.WordBasic.mailmergepropagatelabel
   oDoc.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = False
   oDoc.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False

   Set oDoc = Nothing
   Set oWord = Nothing

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   End Sub
```

This is how the data looks like before and after the code is run from the VBA Editor. I am fairly new to VBA and would appreciate any help!

Sample Data in Excel

[image]

Labels on Word

[image]

Comment: If you want each record to go to a new page, you wouldn't be using a label merge, which is what your code employs, via *oDoc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdMailingLabels*. But then, you also wouldn't be using code like *oWord.Dialogs(wdDialogLabelOptions).Show*
or *oWord.WordBasic.mailmergepropagatelabel*. You need to give a better explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi macropod, What my code currently does is transport data from the sheet to one page in the document in the form of a mail merge. Since it's mostly just name labels and addresses, I was hoping if there is a way to put the labels from each row on a different page in the same document.

Comment: I am definitely open to new methods of doing this, this was just something I found online and edited a bit. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want a full sheet of labels for each address? Then try this (no VBA involved): Alt+F9 in the main merge document to display the field codes. Remove the { NEXT } field from the second and all following labels. That should repeat the same address on the one sheet, and the next address on a new sheet, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a mailmerge main document with a single label containing all the mergefields required for that label, rather than a sheet of labels, and combine that with an ordinary letter merge. Having created the mailmerge main document with a single label, you can then use code like the following:

```
Sub RunMerge()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim StrMMSrc As String, StrMMDoc As String
StrMMSrc = ThisWorkbook.FullName
StrMMDoc = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MailMergeMainDocument.doc"
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=StrMMDoc, AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    With .MailMerge
      .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
      .OpenDataSource Name:=StrMMSrc, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
        "Data Source=StrMMSrc;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`"
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
  .Activate
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Naturally, you may need to edit the 'StrMMDoc' variable to suit your setup & document name and, perhaps, edit the SQL Statement:

SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`"

to reference the correct worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions, I did however find something close to what I was looking for, here is the link for those of you that are curious to know: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URF3ikW0Svc